# How to edit two files at once in Wollok Ide?

Tags: wollok

I would like to edit two files at once, is there any way to have two open files at once?

I know that it is based on Eclipse, but I do not know how to do it in Eclipse either.

Answer (score 2):

You can just drag some editor to the side of the screen and you will be able to see both of them side by side.

[image: Dragging to have two editors]